# Can't create new table in mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp, openfire, create-table

I am trying to run the following query in the created table, but the every time I run it the error shows up of 1064.

Query is-

```
CREATE TABLE ofRosterGroups (
  rosterID              BIGINT          NOT NULL,
  rank                  TINYINT         NOT NULL,
  groupName             VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (rosterID, rank),
  INDEX ofRosterGroup_rosterid_idx (rosterID)
);
```

but seems like it is throwing error every time I made updates to. I don't know what is going wrong with it.

Error coming up is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank TINYINT NOT NULL, groupName
>       VARCHAR at line 3

Comment: Do not give error please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f7930

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on the version of mysql.
Give a try to the following query

```
CREATE TABLE `ofrostergroups` (
  `rosterID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `rank` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `groupName` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE `ofrostergroups`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`rosterID`,`rank`),
  ADD KEY `ofRosterGroup_rosterid_idx` (`rosterID`);
```